# Could not execute method of the activity with thread

Tags: android, illegalstateexception

I have a button with its onClick property "onClick" like this `android:onClick="onClick"`. I am running this in android 2.3.3

Here's the click function in the main activity. This function is outside the OnCreate method as expected.

```
    public void onClick(View v){

    final String textUpdate= editStatus.getText().toString();
     new Thread(new Runnable(){
     public void run() {
            try {

            Twitter twitter = new Twitter("student", "password");
            twitter.setAPIRootUrl("http://yamba.marakana.com/api");
            twitter.setStatus(textUpdate);
            } catch (TwitterException e) {

                Log.e(TAG, "Died", e);
                e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
     }).start();
}
```

The problem is whenever I click the button,the app stops working. (Force Close). So Please see the code and tell if you can find the problem.

Thanking you in anticipation.

Here's the Log -

```
> E/AndroidRuntime(613): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(613): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
E/AndroidRuntime(613):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2704)
E/AndroidRuntime(613):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3100)
E/AndroidRuntime(613):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:11644)
E/AndroidRuntime(613):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
E/AndroidRuntime(613):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
E/AndroidRuntime(613):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:126)
E/AndroidRuntime(613):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3997)
E/AndroidRuntime(613):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(613):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
E/AndroidRuntime(613):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
E/AndroidRuntime(613):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
E/AndroidRuntime(613):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(613): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
E/AndroidRuntime(613):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(613):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
E/AndroidRuntime(613):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2699)
E/AndroidRuntime(613):  ... 11 more
E/AndroidRuntime(613): Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: com.example.yamba.StatusActivity$1
E/AndroidRuntime(613):  at com.example.yamba.StatusActivity.onClick(StatusActivity.java:31)
E/AndroidRuntime(613):  ... 14 more
I/Process(613): Sending signal. PID: 613 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code with the debugger to find the line causing the error?

Comment: the problem is in the line 31 of my activity called StatusActivity and that correspends to the creation of the thread in the code above

Comment: Actually the problem is related to the class Twitter contained in a jar that i added to the project, when i execute the program this class can't be found. I had to  tick the box for this jar in Properties -> Java Build Path -> "Order and Export" (it was listed before, but not selected) and then clean the project and it works